# Copy range between workbooks

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy a range of cells on a sheet in one workbook to the bottom of a sheet in another workbook. I keep getting "Application-defined or object-defined error" on the copy line.

```
Dim NewFileName As String
Dim BAHFileName As String

NewFileName = "Filename"
BAHFileName = "Other Filename"

LastRow = Sheets("All").UsedRange.Rows.Count
Workbooks(NewFileName).Sheets("All").Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(LastRow, 15)).Copy

Windows(BAHFileName & ".xlsx").Activate
LastRow = Workbooks(BAHFileName).Sheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1
Workbooks(BAHFileName).Sheets(1).Cells(LastRow, 1).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Talking to yourself?

Practise with this code to avoid using selects.

I am not sure of the situation of your workbooks, so you will have to adjust workbook names and sheet names accordingly.

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim WB As Workbook
    Dim bk As Workbook
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim Lrow As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim sh As Worksheet

    Set WB = ThisWorkbook
    Set bk = Workbooks("MyWorkbook.xlsx")
    Set ws = WB.Sheets("All")
    Set sh = bk.Sheets(1)

    With ws
        LastRow = .UsedRange.Rows.Count
        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(LastRow, 15))
    End With

    With sh
        Lrow = .UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1
        rng.Copy .Cells(Lrow, 1)
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I needed to select the sheet before copying.

```
Dim NewFileName As String
Dim BAHFileName As String

NewFileName = "Filename"
BAHFileName = "Other Filename"

LastRow = Sheets("All").UsedRange.Rows.Count
Sheets("All").Select
Workbooks(NewFileName).Sheets("All").Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(LastRow, 15)).Copy

Windows(BAHFileName & ".xlsx").Activate
LastRow = Workbooks(BAHFileName).Sheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1
Workbooks(BAHFileName).Sheets(1).Cells(LastRow, 1).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Comment: Great job figuring that out by yourself!

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying my best.